# How can I fix "Conversion from SOAP failed" fault while consuming mainframe web service in VB .Net web service?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, mainframe

I'm currently working on a VB. Net web service calling another web service running in the mainframe. I was provided with the WSDL file and I generated a proxy class using wsdl.exe. Upon attempting to invoke the method of the mainframe web service using the proxy class, I encountered an exception saying "Conversion from SOAP failed" coming from a line of code in the generated proxy class.

```
Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("WSIBACTPOperation", New Object() {WSIBACTPOperation1})
```

Any idea what is causing this? I was told that I don't need to use any certificate. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not use "Add Service Reference", or svcutil.exe?

Comment: Add Service Reference will generate the same proxy class right? I usually organize sources in folders and I just feel more comfortable being able to manage the proxy class source like the others. Yeah I know, doesn't make a lot of sense. But in our current setup that helps us protect our proxy classes from getting overridden by some rather unruly developers.

Comment: No, it will not generate the same class. It will generate a similar class, but using the WCF infrastructure instead of the legacy ASMX infrastructure.

Comment: This is actually a legacy system running on .Net 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out myself. The web service was only requiring COMPLETE AND CORRECT INPUTS. The developer on the customer's side made a mistake when she told us that some of the inputs were not required and therefore can be left blank. Double-checking the WSDL file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the SOAP message coming back from the mainframe.  Does it look like a SOAP message, or does it look like HTML or plain text indicating you aren't authorized?

When you were told you didn't need to use any certificate, were you told you should use BASICAUTH?